# Error en compilación

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]estoy intentando compilar una aplicación, tenía unos errores por algunas dependencias que ya se solucionaron, pero me sigue marcando este error:

El comando "nuget pack "C:....\Core.csproj" -Properties Configuration=Debug -IncludeReferencedProjects -OutputDirectory "C:...Packages"" salió con el código 9009. ...Commands.Core

este error se replica para los proyectos asociados. Alguien tiene alguna idea de como lo podría solucionar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Error 9009` significa que **Visual Studio** no puede encontrar un ejecutable. Normalmente, uno utilizado en un paso de compilación anterior o posterior. En este caso, parece que **NuGet** es el origen del problema.

¿Es posible que esté utilizando una solución que administra dependencias mediante **NuGet** (y probablemente tiene habilitada la opción "Habilitar restauración de paquetes **NuGet**"), pero aún no ha cargado la extensión **NuGet** en **Visual Studio** 2012?

Para confirmar si este es el caso, vaya al menú **Herramientas** y haga clic en **"Extensiones y actualizaciones"**, seleccione **instalado** y escriba en el cuadro de búsqueda en la esquina superior derecha del formulario **Extensiones y actualizaciones**. Si está instalado, debería verlo listado con un número de versión, por ejemplo, *2.4.40116.9051*, que creo que es la versión más reciente como tipo de esto.

Si no lo encuentra, seleccione "**en línea**" en la lista en el lado izquierdo del formulario **Extensiones y actualizaciones**. Busque la entrada **Administrador de paquetes NuGet** (posiblemente el primer elemento de la lista) y haga clic en "**descargar**" para capturarlo.